# HTML Table Scroll Function Over X and Y Axis

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I've created a table that is contained within a section of my webpage and can scroll over the x and y axis to view everything. My problem so far is that the table can scroll along the y-axis when overflowing, but not the x-axis.

In my CSS, I've specified that on the overflow of both, they should both be able to scroll, but only the y-axis works. How would I ensure that the x-axis is scrollable also in order to see the rest of my table?

HTML:

```
<div id="table-wrapper-tasks">
  <div id="table-scroll-tasks">
    <script>
      var rows = document.getElementById('dayRow').getElementsByTagName("td").length;
      var cols = document.getElementById('employeeCol').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
      var rowT = null;

      var drawTable = '<table class="tableTasks">';
        for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          drawTable += '<tr>';
          for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            drawTable += '<td>Testing</td>';
          }
          drawTable += '</tr>';
        }
        drawTable += '</table>';

        document.write(drawTable);
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Settings for Tasks table */
.tableTasks {
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:5px;
  empty-cells: show;
  height:1000px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
}
#table-wrapper-tasks {
  position: relative;
  width:81%;
  float:right;
}

#table-scroll-tasks {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 520px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you are specifying float property. If you remove it things should work fine.

```
.tableTasks {
  width:100%;
  margin-top:5px;
  empty-cells: show;
  height:1000px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked great, I'm still trying to learn HTML so I'm sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Not an issue :)